# How to use a paramater to determine a variable using a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, parameters, src

Can anyone help me understand why this script won't update the iFrame panel when using the loadPages()? Haven't written code in ages and building a website. Is there a better way to swap the iFrame src? Thanks!

```html
<a href="#Gallery" onclick="return loadPages(1)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil"></span></a>
  
<a href="#Gallery" onclick="return loadPages(2)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></span></a>

<script>
        function loadPages(a){
            var loc1 = "http://jquery.com/";
            var loc2 = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
           If (a == 1){
            document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc1);
             }
           If (a == 2){
            document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc2);
             }
        }
</script>
  
<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0" style="border: 0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your code is working ...

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is not proper, change to::

```
function loadPages(a){
    var loc1 = "http://jquery.com/";
    var loc2 = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
    if (a == 1){
        document.getElementById('myFrame').src = loc1;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('myFrame').src = loc2;
    }
}
```

or you can write it as::

```
function loadPages(a){
    var loc = (a == 1) ? "http://jquery.com/" : "http://www.w3schools.com/";
    document.getElementById('myFrame').src = loc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little silly .There is missing close tag `a` and `if` not `If` ....

```
<a href="#Gallery" onclick="return loadPages(1)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil"></span></a>

<a href="#Gallery" onclick="return loadPages(2)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></span></a>

<script>
        function loadPages(a){
            var loc1 = "http://jquery.com/";
            var loc2 = "http://www.w3schools.com/";
           if(a == 1){
            document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc1);
                }
           if(a == 2){
            document.getElementById('myFrame').setAttribute('src', loc2);
                }
        }
</script>

<iframe id="myFrame" src="http://www.google.com" width="100%" height="800" frameborder="0" style="border: 0" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
```